# Is it possible to scrape an Angular Website using Selenium-python?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have been trying to scrape an Angular Website using Selenium. To my surprise it doesn't let you scrape the html rendered contents as it renders it dynamically using Javascript. I want to locate those tags for the purpose of scraping but I am unable to do so. What is the right way to scrape them? Here is some more context:

They say you can't do it using [python](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/webscraping-in-python/).

Some also tried downloading all the html content and then read [them](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/webscraping-in-python/). But again this isn't my use case.

But my use case is a lot different:

I want to login to my google account then it redirects me to an angular page where I click a button called `reporting` and from there I am redirected to a page from where I have to finally click download button to download the report.